# Undefined control sequence BibTex

Tags: bibtex

This is one of the BibTex entries giving the problem:

```
@ARTICLE{2015ApJ...808L..36B,
   author = {{Bonnivard}, V. and {Combet}, C. and {Maurin}, D. and {Geringer-Sameth}, A. and 
    {Koushiappas}, S.~M. and {Walker}, M.~G. and {Mateo}, M. and 
    {Olszewski}, E.~W. and {Bailey}, III, J.~I.},
    title = "{Dark Matter Annihilation and Decay Profiles for the Reticulum II Dwarf Spheroidal Galaxy}",
  journal = {\apjl},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {1504.03309},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.HE",
 keywords = {dark matter, galaxies: dwarf, galaxies: individual: Reticulum II, gamma rays: galaxies, methods: statistical, stars: kinematics and dynamics},
     year = 2015,
    month = aug,
   volume = 808,
      eid = {L36},
    pages = {L36},
      doi = {10.1088/2041-8205/808/2/L36},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015ApJ...808L..36B},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

and corresponding bbl file giving the error at compilation is

```
\bibitem{2009ApJ...697.1071A}
{\sc W.~B. {Atwood}, A.~A. {Abdo}, M.~{Ackermann}, W.~{Althouse},
  B.~{Anderson}, M.~{Axelsson}, L.~{Baldini}, J.~{Ballet}, D.~L. {Band},
  G.~{Barbiellini}, and et~al.}
\newblock {\bf {The Large Area Telescope on the Fermi Gamma-Ray Space Telescope
  Mission}}.
\newblock {\em \apj}, {\bf 697}:1071--1102, June 2009.
```

My guess is that Kile doesn't like references of the form `2015ApJ...808L..36B` since these are the only ones giving the error.

Can somebody hint me to the problem in this? Thank you very much

Comment: Doe you have something like `\newcommand\apjl{The Astrophysical Journal Letters}`?

Comment: And for the second reference `\newcommand\apj{The Astrophysical Journal}`

Comment: Please edit your posting to report the exact wording of the error message(s). I strongly doubt that there's a problem with the key `2015ApJ...808L..36B`. How and where are the macros `\apj` and `\apjl` defined? Are the macro definitions provided in the bib file? If not, where else? Incidentally, which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: Let me guess, did you get the bib entries of the problematic publications from ads? From the ads website: "Please note that our BibTeX entries make use of the AASTeX macro definitions for the most popular astronomical journals. If you're not using the AASTeX package then you will need to include these macros in your LaTeX source. " http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/faq.html#bibtex

Comment: yes yes yes, you are all right. I'm using a Latex template from the university, not the ones provided by the journals. thank you all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the citation keys of the problematic entries, I would guess they originate from ADS.

From the [ADS FAQ:](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/faq.html#bibtex)

> Please note that our BibTeX entries make use of the [AASTeX macro definitions](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.html) for the most popular astronomical journals. If you're not using the [AASTeX package](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html) then you will need to include [these macros](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty) in your LaTeX source.

In its current state, your document seems to be missing suitable definitions for 
`\apjl` and `\apj`.

Answer (score 1):

Save this file of macros:
http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty

and then `\usepackage{aas_macros}`

Comment: It's related to his specific problem: these macros are typical of some astrophysics journals. They are nothing magic, but the exact solution to his problem (the "website" from which he takes his Bibtex entries uses them).
I think it's worth keeping the question and the answer here because many other astrophysicists will have the same problem at a certain point.

Comment: Well, at last it is already mentioned by the accepted answer ...

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer has the merit to identify the problem as the macros. My contribution is to give the right macros, without defining them one by one by hand (in the comments of the previous post there are suggestion to use \newcommand). I think it is helpful, because the next astrophysics grad student that will need to use bibtex for his thesis, will google for this problem: in this way he will find a complete and quick answer.