# "! File ended while scanning use of \@lbibitem" error while citing an article

Tags: bibliographies, errors, citing

I am getting the following error (marked as "runaway argument?") while citing an article:

```
{\citenamefont {{Abbott}}\ \emph {et~al.}(2020)\citenamefont {{Abbott\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@lbibitem.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.19 \bibliography{ref}
                       
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.
```

The minimal code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[aps,prd,reprint,groupeaddress,showpacs,preprintnumbers,nofootinbib,nobibnotes,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}



\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{natbib}

 


\begin{document}

\cite{2020ApJ...896L..44A}



\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

The BibTex code for the article I am citing is :

```
@ARTICLE{2020ApJ...896L..44A,
       author = {{Abbott}, R. and {Abbott}, T.~D. and {Abraham}, S. and {Acernese}, F. and {Ackley}, K. and {Adams}, C. and {Adhikari}, R.~X. and {Adya}, V.~B. and {Affeldt}, C. and {Agathos}, M. and {Agatsuma}, K. and {Aggarwal}, N. and {Aguiar}, O.~D. and {Aich}, A. and {Aiello}, L. and {Ain}, A. and {Ajith}, P. and {Akcay}, S. and {Allen}, G. and {Allocca}, A. and {Altin}, P.~A. and {Amato}, A. and {Anand}, S. and {Ananyeva}, A. and {Anderson}, S.~B. and {Anderson}, W.~G. and {Angelova}, S.~V. and {Ansoldi}, S. and {Antier}, S. and {Appert}, S. and {Arai}, K. and {Araya}, M.~C. and {Areeda}, J.~S. and {Ar{\`e}ne}, M. and {Arnaud}, N. and {Aronson}, S.~M. and {Arun}, K.~G. and {Asali}, Y. and {Ascenzi}, S. and {Ashton}, G. and {Aston}, S.~M. and {Astone}, P. and {Aubin}, F. and {Aufmuth}, P. and {AultONeal}, K. and {Austin}, C. and {Avendano}, V. and {Babak}, S. and {Bacon}, P. and {Badaracco}, F. and {Bader}, M.~K.~M. and {Bae}, S. and {Baer}, A.~M. and {Baird}, J. and {Baldaccini}, F. and {Ballardin}, G. and {Ballmer}, S.~W. and {Bals}, A. and {Balsamo}, A. and {Baltus}, G. and {Banagiri}, S. and {Bankar}, D. and {Bankar}, R.~S. and {Barayoga}, J.~C. and {Barbieri}, C. and {Barish}, B.~C. and {Barker}, D. and {Barkett}, K. and {Barneo}, P. and {Barone}, F. and {Barr}, B. and {Barsotti}, L. and {Barsuglia}, M. and {Barta}, D. and {Bartlett}, J. and {Bartos}, I. and {Bassiri}, R. and {Basti}, A. and {Bawaj}, M. and {Bayley}, J.~C. and {Bazzan}, M. and {B{\'e}csy}, B. and {Bejger}, M. and {Belahcene}, I. and {Bell}, A.~S. and {Beniwal}, D. and {Benjamin}, M.~G. and {Benkel}, R. and {Bentley}, J.~D. and {Bergamin}, F. and {Berger}, B.~K. and {Bergmann}, G. and {Bernuzzi}, S. and {Berry}, C.~P.~L. and {Bersanetti}, D. and {Bertolini}, A. and {Betzwieser}, J. and {Bhandare}, R. and {Bhandari}, A.~V. and {Bidler}, J. and {Biggs}, E. and {Bilenko}, I.~A. and {Billingsley}, G. and {Birney}, R. and {Birnholtz}, O. and {Biscans}, S. and {Bischi}, M. and {Biscoveanu}, S. and {Bisht}, A. and {Bissenbayeva}, G. and {Bitossi}, M. and {Bizouard}, M.~A. and {Blackburn}, J.~K. and {Blackman}, J. and {Blair}, C.~D. and {Blair}, D.~G. and {Blair}, R.~M. and {Bobba}, F. and {Bode}, N. and {Boer}, M. and {Boetzel}, Y. and {Bogaert}, G. and {Bondu}, F. and {Bonilla}, E. and {Bonnand}, R. and {Booker}, P. and {Boom}, B.~A. and {Bork}, R. and {Boschi}, V. and {Bose}, S. and {Bossilkov}, V. and {Bosveld}, J. and {Bouffanais}, Y. and {Bozzi}, A. and {Bradaschia}, C. and {Brady}, P.~R. and {Bramley}, A. and {Branchesi}, M. and {Brau}, J.~E. and {Breschi}, M. and {Briant}, T. and {Briggs}, J.~H. and {Brighenti}, F. and {Brillet}, A. and {Brinkmann}, M. and {Brito}, R. and {Brockill}, P. and {Brooks}, A.~F. and {Brooks}, J. and {Brown}, D.~D. and {Brunett}, S. and {Bruno}, G. and {Bruntz}, R. and {Buikema}, A. and {Bulik}, T. and {Bulten}, H.~J. and {Buonanno}, A. and {Buskulic}, D. and {Byer}, R.~L. and {Cabero}, M. and {Cadonati}, L. and {Cagnoli}, G. and {Cahillane}, C. and {Bustillo}, J. Calder{\'o}n and {Callaghan}, J.~D. and {Callister}, T.~A. and {Calloni}, E. and {Camp}, J.~B. and {Canepa}, M. and {Cannon}, K.~C. and {Cao}, H. and {Cao}, J. and {Carapella}, G. and {Carbognani}, F. and {Caride}, S. and {Carney}, M.~F. and {Carullo}, G. and {Diaz}, J. Casanueva and {Casentini}, C. and {Casta{\~n}eda}, J. and {Caudill}, S. and {Cavagli{\`a}}, M. and {Cavalier}, F. and {Cavalieri}, R. and {Cella}, G. and {Cerd{\'a}-Dur{\'a}n}, P. and {Cesarini}, E. and {Chaibi}, O. and {Chakravarti}, K. and {Chan}, C. and {Chan}, M. and {Chao}, S. and {Charlton}, P. and {Chase}, E.~A. and {Chassande-Mottin}, E. and {Chatterjee}, D. and {Chaturvedi}, M. and {Chatziioannou}, K. and {Chen}, H.~Y. and {Chen}, X. and {Chen}, Y. and {Cheng}, H. -P. and {Cheong}, C.~K. and {Chia}, H.~Y. and {Chiadini}, F. and {Chierici}, R. and {Chincarini}, A. and {Chiummo}, A. and {Cho}, G. and {Cho}, H.~S. and {Cho}, M. and {Christensen}, N. and {Chu}, Q. and {Chua}, S. and {Chung}, K.~W. and {Chung}, S. and {Ciani}, G. and {Ciecielag}, P. and {Cie{\'s}lar}, M. and {Ciobanu}, A.~A. and {Ciolfi}, R. and {Cipriano}, F. and {Cirone}, A. and {Clara}, F. and {Clark}, J.~A. and {Clearwater}, P. and {Clesse}, S. and {Cleva}, F. and {Coccia}, E. and {Cohadon}, P. -F. and {Cohen}, D. and {Colleoni}, M. and {Collette}, C.~G. and {Collins}, C. and {Colpi}, M. and {Constancio}, M., Jr. and {Conti}, L. and {Cooper}, S.~J. and {Corban}, P. and {Corbitt}, T.~R. and {Cordero-Carri{\'o}n}, I. and {Corezzi}, S. and {Corley}, K.~R. and {Cornish}, N. and {Corre}, D. and {Corsi}, A. and {Cortese}, S. and {Costa}, C.~A. and {Cotesta}, R. and {Coughlin}, M.~W. and {Coughlin}, S.~B. and {Coulon}, J. -P. and {Countryman}, S.~T. and {Couvares}, P. and {Covas}, P.~B. and {Coward}, D.~M. and {Cowart}, M.~J. and {Coyne}, D.~C. and {Coyne}, R. and {Creighton}, J.~D.~E. and {Creighton}, T.~D. and {Cripe}, J. and {Croquette}, M. and {Crowder}, S.~G. and {Cudell}, J. -R. and {Cullen}, T.~J. and {Cumming}, A. and {Cummings}, R. and {Cunningham}, L. and {Cuoco}, E. and {Curylo}, M. and {Canton}, T. Dal and {D{\'a}lya}, G. and {Dana}, A. and {Daneshgaran-Bajastani}, L.~M. and {D'Angelo}, B. and {Danilishin}, S.~L. and {D'Antonio}, S. and {Danzmann}, K. and {Darsow-Fromm}, C. and {Dasgupta}, A. and {Datrier}, L.~E.~H. and {Dattilo}, V. and {Dave}, I. and {Davier}, M. and {Davies}, G.~S. and {Davis}, D. and {Daw}, E.~J. and {DeBra}, D. and {Deenadayalan}, M. and {Degallaix}, J. and {De Laurentis}, M. and {Del{\'e}glise}, S. and {Delfavero}, M. and {De Lillo}, N. and {Del Pozzo}, W. and {DeMarchi}, L.~M. and {D'Emilio}, V. and {Demos}, N. and {Dent}, T. and {De Pietri}, R. and {De Rosa}, R. and {De Rossi}, C. and {DeSalvo}, R. and {de Varona}, O. and {Dhurandhar}, S. and {D{\'\i}az}, M.~C. and {Diaz-Ortiz}, M., Jr. and {Dietrich}, T. and {Di Fiore}, L. and {Di Fronzo}, C. and {Di Giorgio}, C. and {Di Giovanni}, F. and {Di Giovanni}, M. and {Di Girolamo}, T. and {Di Lieto}, A. and {Ding}, B. and {Di Pace}, S. and {Di Palma}, I. and {Di Renzo}, F. and {Divakarla}, A.~K. and {Dmitriev}, A. and {Doctor}, Z. and {Donovan}, F. and {Dooley}, K.~L. and {Doravari}, S. and {Dorrington}, I. and {Downes}, T.~P. and {Drago}, M. and {Driggers}, J.~C. and {Du}, Z. and {Ducoin}, J. -G. and {Dupej}, P. and {Durante}, O. and {D'Urso}, D. and {Dwyer}, S.~E. and {Easter}, P.~J. and {Eddolls}, G. and {Edelman}, B. and {Edo}, T.~B. and {Edy}, O. and {Effler}, A. and {Ehrens}, P. and {Eichholz}, J. and {Eikenberry}, S.~S. and {Eisenmann}, M. and {Eisenstein}, R.~A. and {Ejlli}, A. and {Errico}, L. and {Essick}, R.~C. and {Estelles}, H. and {Estevez}, D. and {Etienne}, Z.~B. and {Etzel}, T. and {Evans}, M. and {Evans}, T.~M. and {Ewing}, B.~E. and {Fafone}, V. and {Fairhurst}, S. and {Fan}, X. and {Farinon}, S. and {Farr}, B. and {Farr}, W.~M. and {Fauchon-Jones}, E.~J. and {Favata}, M. and {Fays}, M. and {Fazio}, M. and {Feicht}, J. and {Fejer}, M.~M. and {Feng}, F. and {Fenyvesi}, E. and {Ferguson}, D.~L. and {Fernandez-Galiana}, A. and {Ferrante}, I. and {Ferreira}, E.~C. and {Ferreira}, T.~A. and {Fidecaro}, F. and {Fiori}, I. and {Fiorucci}, D. and {Fishbach}, M. and {Fisher}, R.~P. and {Fittipaldi}, R. and {Fitz-Axen}, M. and {Fiumara}, V. and {Flaminio}, R. and {Floden}, E. and {Flynn}, E. and {Fong}, H. and {Font}, J.~A. and {Forsyth}, P.~W.~F. and {Fournier}, J. -D. and {Frasca}, S. and {Frasconi}, F. and {Frei}, Z. and {Freise}, A. and {Frey}, R. and {Frey}, V. and {Fritschel}, P. and {Frolov}, V.~V. and {Fronz{\`e}}, G. and {Fulda}, P. and {Fyffe}, M. and {Gabbard}, H.~A. and {Gadre}, B.~U. and {Gaebel}, S.~M. and {Gair}, J.~R. and {Galaudage}, S. and {Ganapathy}, D. and {Ganguly}, A. and {Gaonkar}, S.~G. and {Garc{\'\i}a-Quir{\'o}s}, C. and {Garufi}, F. and {Gateley}, B. and {Gaudio}, S. and {Gayathri}, V. and {Gemme}, G. and {Genin}, E. and {Gennai}, A. and {George}, D. and {George}, J. and {Gergely}, L. and {Ghonge}, S. and {Ghosh}, Abhirup and {Ghosh}, Archisman and {Ghosh}, S. and {Giacomazzo}, B. and {Giaime}, J.~A. and {Giardina}, K.~D. and {Gibson}, D.~R. and {Gier}, C. and {Gill}, K. and {Glanzer}, J. and {Gniesmer}, J. and {Godwin}, P. and {Goetz}, E. and {Goetz}, R. and {Gohlke}, N. and {Goncharov}, B. and {Gonz{\'a}lez}, G. and {Gopakumar}, A. and {Gossan}, S.~E. and {Gosselin}, M. and {Gouaty}, R. and {Grace}, B. and {Grado}, A. and {Granata}, M. and {Grant}, A. and {Gras}, S. and {Grassia}, P. and {Gray}, C. and {Gray}, R. and {Greco}, G. and {Green}, A.~C. and {Green}, R. and {Gretarsson}, E.~M. and {Griggs}, H.~L. and {Grignani}, G. and {Grimaldi}, A. and {Grimm}, S.~J. and {Grote}, H. and {Grunewald}, S. and {Gruning}, P. and {Guidi}, G.~M. and {Guimaraes}, A.~R. and {Guix{\'e}}, G. and {Gulati}, H.~K. and {Guo}, Y. and {Gupta}, A. and {Gupta}, Anchal and {Gupta}, P. and {Gustafson}, E.~K. and {Gustafson}, R. and {Haegel}, L. and {Halim}, O. and {Hall}, E.~D. and {Hamilton}, E.~Z. and {Hammond}, G. and {Haney}, M. and {Hanke}, M.~M. and {Hanks}, J. and {Hanna}, C. and {Hannam}, M.~D. and {Hannuksela}, O.~A. and {Hansen}, T.~J. and {Hanson}, J. and {Harder}, T. and {Hardwick}, T. and {Haris}, K. and {Harms}, J. and {Harry}, G.~M. and {Harry}, I.~W. and {Hasskew}, R.~K. and {Haster}, C. -J. and {Haughian}, K. and {Hayes}, F.~J. and {Healy}, J. and {Heidmann}, A. and {Heintze}, M.~C. and {Heinze}, J. and {Heitmann}, H. and {Hellman}, F. and {Hello}, P. and {Hemming}, G. and {Hendry}, M. and {Heng}, I.~S. and {Hennes}, E. and {Hennig}, J. and {Heurs}, M. and {Hild}, S. and {Hinderer}, T. and {Hoback}, S.~Y. and {Hochheim}, S. and {Hofgard}, E. and {Hofman}, D. and {Holgado}, A.~M. and {Holland}, N.~A. and {Holt}, K. and {Holz}, D.~E. and {Hopkins}, P. and {Horst}, C. and {Hough}, J. and {Howell}, E.~J. and {Hoy}, C.~G. and {Huang}, Y. and {H{\"u}bner}, M.~T. and {Huerta}, E.~A. and {Huet}, D. and {Hughey}, B. and {Hui}, V. and {Husa}, S. and {Huttner}, S.~H. and {Huxford}, R. and {Huynh-Dinh}, T. and {Idzkowski}, B. and {Iess}, A. and {Inchauspe}, H. and {Ingram}, C. and {Intini}, G. and {Isac}, J. -M. and {Isi}, M. and {Iyer}, B.~R. and {Jacqmin}, T. and {Jadhav}, S.~J. and {Jadhav}, S.~P. and {James}, A.~L. and {Jani}, K. and {Janthalur}, N.~N. and {Jaranowski}, P. and {Jariwala}, D. and {Jaume}, R. and {Jenkins}, A.~C. and {Jiang}, J. and {Johns}, G.~R. and {Johnson-McDaniel}, N.~K. and {Jones}, A.~W. and {Jones}, D.~I. and {Jones}, J.~D. and {Jones}, P. and {Jones}, R. and {Jonker}, R.~J.~G. and {Ju}, L. and {Junker}, J. and {Kalaghatgi}, C.~V. and {Kalogera}, V. and {Kamai}, B. and {Kandhasamy}, S. and {Kang}, G. and {Kanner}, J.~B. and {Kapadia}, S.~J. and {Karki}, S. and {Kashyap}, R. and {Kasprzack}, M. and {Kastaun}, W. and {Katsanevas}, S. and {Katsavounidis}, E. and {Katzman}, W. and {Kaufer}, S. and {Kawabe}, K. and {K{\'e}f{\'e}lian}, F. and {Keitel}, D. and {Keivani}, A. and {Kennedy}, R. and {Key}, J.~S. and {Khadka}, S. and {Khalili}, F.~Y. and {Khan}, I. and {Khan}, S. and {Khan}, Z.~A. and {Khazanov}, E.~A. and {Khetan}, N. and {Khursheed}, M. and {Kijbunchoo}, N. and {Kim}, Chunglee and {Kim}, G.~J. and {Kim}, J.~C. and {Kim}, K. and {Kim}, W. and {Kim}, W.~S. and {Kim}, Y. -M. and {Kimball}, C. and {King}, P.~J. and {Kinley-Hanlon}, M. and {Kirchhoff}, R. and {Kissel}, J.~S. and {Kleybolte}, L. and {Klimenko}, S. and {Knowles}, T.~D. and {Knyazev}, E. and {Koch}, P. and {Koehlenbeck}, S.~M. and {Koekoek}, G. and {Koley}, S. and {Kondrashov}, V. and {Kontos}, A. and {Koper}, N. and {Korobko}, M. and {Korth}, W.~Z. and {Kovalam}, M. and {Kozak}, D.~B. and {Kringel}, V. and {Krishnendu}, N.~V. and {Kr{\'o}lak}, A. and {Krupinski}, N. and {Kuehn}, G. and {Kumar}, A. and {Kumar}, P. and {Kumar}, Rahul and {Kumar}, Rakesh and {Kumar}, S. and {Kuo}, L. and {Kutynia}, A. and {Lackey}, B.~D. and {Laghi}, D. and {Lalande}, E. and {Lam}, T.~L. and {Lamberts}, A. and {Landry}, M. and {Landry}, P. and {Lane}, B.~B. and {Lang}, R.~N. and {Lange}, J. and {Lantz}, B. and {Lanza}, R.~K. and {La Rosa}, I. and {Lartaux-Vollard}, A. and {Lasky}, P.~D. and {Laxen}, M. and {Lazzarini}, A. and {Lazzaro}, C. and {Leaci}, P. and {Leavey}, S. and {Lecoeuche}, Y.~K. and {Lee}, C.~H. and {Lee}, H.~M. and {Lee}, H.~W. and {Lee}, J. and {Lee}, K. and {Lehmann}, J. and {Leroy}, N. and {Letendre}, N. and {Levin}, Y. and {Li}, A.~K.~Y. and {Li}, J. and {li}, K. and {Li}, T.~G.~F. and {Li}, X. and {Linde}, F. and {Linker}, S.~D. and {Linley}, J.~N. and {Littenberg}, T.~B. and {Liu}, J. and {Liu}, X. and {Llorens-Monteagudo}, M. and {Lo}, R.~K.~L. and {Lockwood}, A. and {London}, L.~T. and {Longo}, A. and {Lorenzini}, M. and {Loriette}, V. and {Lormand}, M. and {Losurdo}, G. and {Lough}, J.~D. and {Lousto}, C.~O. and {Lovelace}, G. and {L{\"u}ck}, H. and {Lumaca}, D. and {Lundgren}, A.~P. and {Ma}, Y. and {Macas}, R. and {Macfoy}, S. and {MacInnis}, M. and {Macleod}, D.~M. and {MacMillan}, I.~A.~O. and {Macquet}, A. and {Hernandez}, I. Maga{\~n}a and {Maga{\~n}a-Sandoval}, F. and {Magee}, R.~M. and {Majorana}, E. and {Maksimovic}, I. and {Malik}, A. and {Man}, N. and {Mandic}, V. and {Mangano}, V. and {Mansell}, G.~L. and {Manske}, M. and {Mantovani}, M. and {Mapelli}, M. and {Marchesoni}, F. and {Marion}, F. and {M{\'a}rka}, S. and {M{\'a}rka}, Z. and {Markakis}, C. and {Markosyan}, A.~S. and {Markowitz}, A. and {Maros}, E. and {Marquina}, A. and {Marsat}, S. and {Martelli}, F. and {Martin}, I.~W. and {Martin}, R.~M. and {Martinez}, V. and {Martynov}, D.~V. and {Masalehdan}, H. and {Mason}, K. and {Massera}, E. and {Masserot}, A. and {Massinger}, T.~J. and {Masso-Reid}, M. and {Mastrogiovanni}, S. and {Matas}, A. and {Matichard}, F. and {Mavalvala}, N. and {Maynard}, E. and {McCann}, J.~J. and {McCarthy}, R. and {McClelland}, D.~E. and {McCormick}, S. and {McCuller}, L. and {McGuire}, S.~C. and {McIsaac}, C. and {McIver}, J. and {McManus}, D.~J. and {McRae}, T. and {McWilliams}, S.~T. and {Meacher}, D. and {Meadors}, G.~D. and {Mehmet}, M. and {Mehta}, A.~K. and {Villa}, E. Mejuto and {Melatos}, A. and {Mendell}, G. and {Mercer}, R.~A. and {Mereni}, L. and {Merfeld}, K. and {Merilh}, E.~L. and {Merritt}, J.~D. and {Merzougui}, M. and {Meshkov}, S. and {Messenger}, C. and {Messick}, C. and {Metzdorff}, R. and {Meyers}, P.~M. and {Meylahn}, F. and {Mhaske}, A. and {Miani}, A. and {Miao}, H. and {Michaloliakos}, I. and {Michel}, C. and {Middleton}, H. and {Milano}, L. and {Miller}, A.~L. and {Millhouse}, M. and {Mills}, J.~C. and {Milotti}, E. and {Milovich-Goff}, M.~C. and {Minazzoli}, O. and {Minenkov}, Y. and {Mishkin}, A. and {Mishra}, C. and {Mistry}, T. and {Mitra}, S. and {Mitrofanov}, V.~P. and {Mitselmakher}, G. and {Mittleman}, R. and {Mo}, G. and {Mogushi}, K. and {Mohapatra}, S.~R.~P. and {Mohite}, S.~R. and {Molina-Ruiz}, M. and {Mondin}, M. and {Montani}, M. and {Moore}, C.~J. and {Moraru}, D. and {Morawski}, F. and {Moreno}, G. and {Morisaki}, S. and {Mours}, B. and {Mow-Lowry}, C.~M. and {Mozzon}, S. and {Muciaccia}, F. and {Mukherjee}, Arunava and {Mukherjee}, D. and {Mukherjee}, S. and {Mukherjee}, Subroto and {Mukund}, N. and {Mullavey}, A. and {Munch}, J. and {Mu{\~n}iz}, E.~A. and {Murray}, P.~G. and {Nagar}, A. and {Nardecchia}, I. and {Naticchioni}, L. and {Nayak}, R.~K. and {Neil}, B.~F. and {Neilson}, J. and {Nelemans}, G. and {Nelson}, T.~J.~N. and {Nery}, M. and {Neunzert}, A. and {Ng}, K.~Y. and {Ng}, S. and {Nguyen}, C. and {Nguyen}, P. and {Nichols}, D. and {Nichols}, S.~A. and {Nissanke}, S. and {Nocera}, F. and {Noh}, M. and {North}, C. and {Nothard}, D. and {Nuttall}, L.~K. and {Oberling}, J. and {O'Brien}, B.~D. and {Oganesyan}, G. and {Ogin}, G.~H. and {Oh}, J.~J. and {Oh}, S.~H. and {Ohme}, F. and {Ohta}, H. and {Okada}, M.~A. and {Oliver}, M. and {Olivetto}, C. and {Oppermann}, P. and {Oram}, Richard J. and {O'Reilly}, B. and {Ormiston}, R.~G. and {Ortega}, L.~F. and {O'Shaughnessy}, R. and {Ossokine}, S. and {Osthelder}, C. and {Ottaway}, D.~J. and {Overmier}, H. and {Owen}, B.~J. and {Pace}, A.~E. and {Pagano}, G. and {Page}, M.~A. and {Pagliaroli}, G. and {Pai}, A. and {Pai}, S.~A. and {Palamos}, J.~R. and {Palashov}, O. and {Palomba}, C. and {Pan}, H. and {Panda}, P.~K. and {Pang}, P.~T.~H. and {Pankow}, C. and {Pannarale}, F. and {Pant}, B.~C. and {Paoletti}, F. and {Paoli}, A. and {Parida}, A. and {Parker}, W. and {Pascucci}, D. and {Pasqualetti}, A. and {Passaquieti}, R. and {Passuello}, D. and {Patricelli}, B. and {Payne}, E. and {Pearlstone}, B.~L. and {Pechsiri}, T.~C. and {Pedersen}, A.~J. and {Pedraza}, M. and {Pele}, A. and {Penn}, S. and {Perego}, A. and {Perez}, C.~J. and {P{\'e}rigois}, C. and {Perreca}, A. and {Perri{\`e}s}, S. and {Petermann}, J. and {Pfeiffer}, H.~P. and {Phelps}, M. and {Phukon}, K.~S. and {Piccinni}, O.~J. and {Pichot}, M. and {Piendibene}, M. and {Piergiovanni}, F. and {Pierro}, V. and {Pillant}, G. and {Pinard}, L. and {Pinto}, I.~M. and {Piotrzkowski}, K. and {Pirello}, M. and {Pitkin}, M. and {Plastino}, W. and {Poggiani}, R. and {Pong}, D.~Y.~T. and {Ponrathnam}, S. and {Popolizio}, P. and {Porter}, E.~K. and {Powell}, J. and {Prajapati}, A.~K. and {Prasai}, K. and {Prasanna}, R. and {Pratten}, G. and {Prestegard}, T. and {Principe}, M. and {Prodi}, G.~A. and {Prokhorov}, L. and {Punturo}, M. and {Puppo}, P. and {P{\"u}rrer}, M. and {Qi}, H. and {Quetschke}, V. and {Quinonez}, P.~J. and {Raab}, F.~J. and {Raaijmakers}, G. and {Radkins}, H. and {Radulesco}, N. and {Raffai}, P. and {Rafferty}, H. and {Raja}, S. and {Rajan}, C. and {Rajbhandari}, B. and {Rakhmanov}, M. and {Ramirez}, K.~E. and {Ramos-Buades}, A. and {Rana}, Javed and {Rao}, K. and {Rapagnani}, P. and {Raymond}, V. and {Razzano}, M. and {Read}, J. and {Regimbau}, T. and {Rei}, L. and {Reid}, S. and {Reitze}, D.~H. and {Rettegno}, P. and {Ricci}, F. and {Richardson}, C.~J. and {Richardson}, J.~W. and {Ricker}, P.~M. and {Riemenschneider}, G. and {Riles}, K. and {Rizzo}, M. and {Robertson}, N.~A. and {Robinet}, F. and {Rocchi}, A. and {Rodriguez-Soto}, R.~D. and {Rolland}, L. and {Rollins}, J.~G. and {Roma}, V.~J. and {Romanelli}, M. and {Romano}, R. and {Romel}, C.~L. and {Romero-Shaw}, I.~M. and {Romie}, J.~H. and {Rose}, C.~A. and {Rose}, D. and {Rose}, K. and {Rosi{\'n}ska}, D. and {Rosofsky}, S.~G. and {Ross}, M.~P. and {Rowan}, S. and {Rowlinson}, S.~J. and {Roy}, P.~K. and {Roy}, Santosh and {Roy}, Soumen and {Ruggi}, P. and {Rutins}, G. and {Ryan}, K. and {Sachdev}, S. and {Sadecki}, T. and {Sakellariadou}, M. and {Salafia}, O.~S. and {Salconi}, L. and {Saleem}, M. and {Salemi}, F. and {Samajdar}, A. and {Sanchez}, E.~J. and {Sanchez}, L.~E. and {Sanchis-Gual}, N. and {Sanders}, J.~R. and {Santiago}, K.~A. and {Santos}, E. and {Sarin}, N. and {Sassolas}, B. and {Sathyaprakash}, B.~S. and {Sauter}, O. and {Savage}, R.~L. and {Savant}, V. and {Sawant}, D. and {Sayah}, S. and {Schaetzl}, D. and {Schale}, P. and {Scheel}, M. and {Scheuer}, J. and {Schmidt}, P. and {Schnabel}, R. and {Schofield}, R.~M.~S. and {Sch{\"o}nbeck}, A. and {Schreiber}, E. and {Schulte}, B.~W. and {Schutz}, B.~F. and {Schwarm}, O. and {Schwartz}, E. and {Scott}, J. and {Scott}, S.~M. and {Seidel}, E. and {Sellers}, D. and {Sengupta}, A.~S. and {Sennett}, N. and {Sentenac}, D. and {Sequino}, V. and {Sergeev}, A. and {Setyawati}, Y. and {Shaddock}, D.~A. and {Shaffer}, T. and {Shahriar}, M.~S. and {Sharma}, A. and {Sharma}, P. and {Shawhan}, P. and {Shen}, H. and {Shikauchi}, M. and {Shink}, R. and {Shoemaker}, D.~H. and {Shoemaker}, D.~M. and {Shukla}, K. and {ShyamSundar}, S. and {Siellez}, K. and {Sieniawska}, M. and {Sigg}, D. and {Singer}, L.~P. and {Singh}, D. and {Singh}, N. and {Singha}, A. and {Singhal}, A. and {Sintes}, A.~M. and {Sipala}, V. and {Skliris}, V. and {Slagmolen}, B.~J.~J. and {Slaven-Blair}, T.~J. and {Smetana}, J. and {Smith}, J.~R. and {Smith}, R.~J.~E. and {Somala}, S. and {Son}, E.~J. and {Soni}, S. and {Sorazu}, B. and {Sordini}, V. and {Sorrentino}, F. and {Souradeep}, T. and {Sowell}, E. and {Spencer}, A.~P. and {Spera}, M. and {Srivastava}, A.~K. and {Srivastava}, V. and {Staats}, K. and {Stachie}, C. and {Standke}, M. and {Steer}, D.~A. and {Steinhoff}, J. and {Steinke}, M. and {Steinlechner}, J. and {Steinlechner}, S. and {Steinmeyer}, D. and {Stevenson}, S. and {Stocks}, D. and {Stops}, D.~J. and {Stover}, M. and {Strain}, K.~A. and {Stratta}, G. and {Strunk}, A. and {Sturani}, R. and {Stuver}, A.~L. and {Sudhagar}, S. and {Sudhir}, V. and {Summerscales}, T.~Z. and {Sun}, L. and {Sunil}, S. and {Sur}, A. and {Suresh}, J. and {Sutton}, P.~J. and {Swinkels}, B.~L. and {Szczepa{\'n}czyk}, M.~J. and {Tacca}, M. and {Tait}, S.~C. and {Talbot}, C. and {Tanasijczuk}, A.~J. and {Tanner}, D.~B. and {Tao}, D. and {T{\'a}pai}, M. and {Tapia}, A. and {San Martin}, E.~N. Tapia and {Tasson}, J.~D. and {Taylor}, R. and {Tenorio}, R. and {Terkowski}, L. and {Thirugnanasambandam}, M.~P. and {Thomas}, M. and {Thomas}, P. and {Thompson}, J.~E. and {Thondapu}, S.~R. and {Thorne}, K.~A. and {Thrane}, E. and {Tinsman}, C.~L. and {Saravanan}, T.~R. and {Tiwari}, Shubhanshu and {Tiwari}, S. and {Tiwari}, V. and {Toland}, K. and {Tonelli}, M. and {Tornasi}, Z. and {Torres-Forn{\'e}}, A. and {Torrie}, C.~I. and {Tosta e Melo}, I. and {T{\"o}yr{\"a}}, D. and {Trail}, E.~A. and {Travasso}, F. and {Traylor}, G. and {Tringali}, M.~C. and {Tripathee}, A. and {Trovato}, A. and {Trudeau}, R.~J. and {Tsang}, K.~W. and {Tse}, M. and {Tso}, R. and {Tsukada}, L. and {Tsuna}, D. and {Tsutsui}, T. and {Turconi}, M. and {Ubhi}, A.~S. and {Ueno}, K. and {Ugolini}, D. and {Unnikrishnan}, C.~S. and {Urban}, A.~L. and {Usman}, S.~A. and {Utina}, A.~C. and {Vahlbruch}, H. and {Vajente}, G. and {Valdes}, G. and {Valentini}, M. and {van Bakel}, N. and {van Beuzekom}, M. and {van den Brand}, J.~F.~J. and {Van Den Broeck}, C. and {Vander-Hyde}, D.~C. and {van der Schaaf}, L. and {Van Heijningen}, J.~V. and {van Veggel}, A.~A. and {Vardaro}, M. and {Varma}, V. and {Vass}, S. and {Vas{\'u}th}, M. and {Vecchio}, A. and {Vedovato}, G. and {Veitch}, J. and {Veitch}, P.~J. and {Venkateswara}, K. and {Venugopalan}, G. and {Verkindt}, D. and {Veske}, D. and {Vetrano}, F. and {Vicer{\'e}}, A. and {Viets}, A.~D. and {Vinciguerra}, S. and {Vine}, D.~J. and {Vinet}, J. -Y. and {Vitale}, S. and {Vivanco}, Francisco Hernandez and {Vo}, T. and {Vocca}, H. and {Vorvick}, C. and {Vyatchanin}, S.~P. and {Wade}, A.~R. and {Wade}, L.~E. and {Wade}, M. and {Walet}, R. and {Walker}, M. and {Wallace}, G.~S. and {Wallace}, L. and {Walsh}, S. and {Wang}, J.~Z. and {Wang}, S. and {Wang}, W.~H. and {Ward}, R.~L. and {Warden}, Z.~A. and {Warner}, J. and {Was}, M. and {Watchi}, J. and {Weaver}, B. and {Wei}, L. -W. and {Weinert}, M. and {Weinstein}, A.~J. and {Weiss}, R. and {Wellmann}, F. and {Wen}, L. and {We{\ss}els}, P. and {Westhouse}, J.~W. and {Wette}, K. and {Whelan}, J.~T. and {Whiting}, B.~F. and {Whittle}, C. and {Wilken}, D.~M. and {Williams}, D. and {Willis}, J.~L. and {Willke}, B. and {Winkler}, W. and {Wipf}, C.~C. and {Wittel}, H. and {Woan}, G. and {Woehler}, J. and {Wofford}, J.~K. and {Wong}, C. and {Wright}, J.~L. and {Wu}, D.~S. and {Wysocki}, D.~M. and {Xiao}, L. and {Yamamoto}, H. and {Yang}, L. and {Yang}, Y. and {Yang}, Z. and {Yap}, M.~J. and {Yazback}, M. and {Yeeles}, D.~W. and {Yu}, Hang and {Yu}, Haocun and {Yuen}, S.~H.~R. and {Zadro{\.z}ny}, A.~K. and {Zadro{\.z}ny}, A. and {Zanolin}, M. and {Zelenova}, T. and {Zendri}, J. -P. and {Zevin}, M. and {Zhang}, J. and {Zhang}, L. and {Zhang}, T. and {Zhao}, C. and {Zhao}, G. and {Zhou}, M. and {Zhou}, Z. and {Zhu}, X.~J. and {Zimmerman}, A.~B. and {Zucker}, M.~E. and {Zweizig}, J. and {LIGO Scientific Collaboration} and {Virgo Collaboration}},
        title = "{GW190814: Gravitational Waves from the Coalescence of a 23 Solar Mass Black Hole with a 2.6 Solar Mass Compact Object}",
      journal = {\apjl},
     keywords = {675, 677, 98, 283, 678, 676, Astrophysics - High Energy Astrophysical Phenomena, General Relativity and Quantum Cosmology},
         year = 2020,
        month = jun,
       volume = {896},
       number = {2},
          eid = {L44},
        pages = {L44},
          doi = {10.3847/2041-8213/ab960f},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
       eprint = {2006.12611},
 primaryClass = {astro-ph.HE},
       adsurl = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2020ApJ...896L..44A},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

What is causing this error and what can I do to resolve it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On my machine BibTeX crashes and leaves an incomplete `.bbl` file, presumably because the `author` field is too long. Truncate the field manually to e.g. `author = {Abbott, R. and other},` and try again.

Comment: With your MWE I also get an error about `\apjl` being undefined, because the example uses AAS journal macros, but does not load a relevant package that defines these macros. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468056/35864.

Comment: @moewe shortening the author list and defining the journal using `\newcommand` does the trick. Thanks