# Undefined Control Sequence Error Message as output.bbl Files

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Here is the github link [uathesis](https://github.com/trananh/uathesis) where I am using to write up my dissertation with the newer class `uathesis`.

All I am doing is to replace my text body with that of the templates.

Here is the `dissertation.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[dissertation,CC-BY-ND]{uathesis}

% Package Usage
\usepackage[ruled,boxed,noend]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}         % natbib is available on most systems, and is
                    % terribly handy.
                    % If you want to use a different Bibliography package, 
                    % you should be able to, just change this
                    % and the \bibliographystyle command below.  Be warned
                    % that you may need to do a little hacking to get
                    % the REFERENCES item to show up in your TOC.

\usepackage{aastex_hack}        % Allows other AASTEX functionality.
\usepackage[bookmarks,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}


% Set up some values.
\completetitle{My Lovely Dissertation}
\fullname{Bob Bob Loblaw} % Grad college wants your full name here.
\degreename{Doctor of Philosophy}   % Title of your degree.

\begin{document}

% Set up the title page
\maketitlepage
{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE}    % Title of your department.
{2013}                          

\approval
{1 January 1922}        % Defense Date  
{Arnold Abrams}     % Dissertation Director
{Billy Boy}     % 1st committee member
{Carl Crow}     % 2nd committee member
{Donna Dood}            % 3rd committee member
{Edgar Elm} % 4th committee member (leave empty if None)
{} % 5th committee member (leave empty if None)

% Include the ``Statement by Author'' for Dissertations
\statementbyauthor

% Include the ``Acknowledgements''
\incacknowledgements{acknowledgements}

\incdedication{dedication}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\incabstract{abstract}

\include{mainmatter/introduction}

\appendix
\include{appendix_A}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}      % changing the value
\small\normalsize                                       % switch size to make the value take


\bibliographystyle{uabibnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here is the `introduction.tex` file inside *mainmatter* folder:

```
\chapter{INTRODUCTION\label{chapter:introduction}}

Some Statement \citep[hereafter ETHOS paper]{2016MNRAS.460.1399V}. Some other statement \citep{2016MNRAS.463.1666C}. Still another statement \citep{1993MNRAS.264..201K,1999ApJ...522...82K,1999ApJ...524L..19M}. Yet another statement \citep{2017arXiv171106267K}. The final statement \citep{Tolman511,1934rtc..book.....T,1935ApJ....82..302H,1996ApJ...456L..79P}. 

First statement \citep{2004MNRAS.348..421N}, and \citep{2000ApJ...543..552S,2004MNRAS.348..421N,2005ARA&A..43..861W}. Second statement \citep{2017arXiv170401634R}. Third statement \citep{2011ApJ...743...82M} and \citep{2014ApJ...782L..29R}, as well as \citep{2005ARA&A..43..861W,2015ApJ...800....7N}. Forth statement \citep{2005pgqa.conf..231L}. Final statement \citep{2011MNRAS.418.1796F,2011MNRAS.412L.118F,2011MNRAS.413L..51K,2012MNRAS.421.2809V,2012MNRAS.424.2292G,2013ApJ...775...78F,2013ApJ...765...89S,2014ApJ...780...74F,2015MNRAS.449..987F}.

First Statement \citep{2012arXiv1209.3272T}. Second statement \citep{1986ApJS...61..249W,1989ApJ...344..567T,1991ApJS...77....1L,2000ApJ...543..552S,2003MNRAS.346.1103P,2004PASP..116..622P,2008MNRAS.388.1349E,2009ApJ...696.1543P,2009A&A...505.1087N,2012A&A...547L...1N,2013yCat..35560141Z,2013A&A...556A.140Z,2015MNRAS.452..217C,2016MNRAS.456.4488S}. Third statement \citep{2012A&A...547L...1N} while \citep{2017arXiv170401634R} and \citep{2018MNRAS.473L..54K}. 

First statement \citep{2006ApJ...652..994C,2011MNRAS.417..304L,2008ApJ...687..745C} and stars \citep{2011MNRAS.417..304L,2008ApJ...687..745C,2018ApJ...856L..12N,2011MNRAS.410.2237P,2010MNRAS.402.2520S,2005ApJ...623..767J,2003AAS...20314504C,2001APS..APRB14007G,2000ASPC..215..287C,1998ApJ...501L..11M}.

First statement \citep{1999MNRAS.305L..21B,2001ApJ...554...85W,2003A&A...409..835F,2004MNRAS.347..813H,2005ApJ...635...60T}.

First statement \citep{2017arXiv170401634R}. \cite{2017hsa9.conf..193P} have shown this. Second statement \cite{2018MNRAS.480.4702P}.
```

My `bibliography.bib` file of the project is a lengthy one and as soon as it is replaced with the empty one in the project, I am receiving a bunch of error messages as follows all related to the entries of the bibliography file:

```
 Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

(natbib)                Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.

See the natbib package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.87 ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Check the bibliography entries for non-compliant syntax,
or select author-year BibTeX style, e.g. plainnat
 output.bbl, line 220


Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.231 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1086/311448}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 234

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.234 ...ucher-Gigu{\`e}re}}]{2011ApJ...743...82M}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 239

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.239 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1088/0004-637X/743/1/82}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 242

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.242 ...adel}, and {Tozzi}}]{1999ApJ...524L..19M}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 247

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.247 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1086/312287}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 250

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.250   {Hernquist}}]{2004MNRAS.348..421N}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 255

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.255 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2004.07393.x}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 259

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.259   {Zwaan}}]{2018ApJ...856L..12N}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 263

Missing $ inserted.

Check that your $'s match around math expressions. If they do, then you've probably used a symbol in normal text that needs to be in math mode. Symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ), and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ) must be written in math mode. See the full list here.If you intended to use mathematics mode, then use $ … $ for 'inline math mode', $$ … $$ for 'display math mode' or alternatively \begin{math} … \end{math}.
 Learn more

<inserted text> 
                $
l.263 ...from a Galaxy Associated with a z {\tilde
                                                  } 2.2
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.263 ...rom a Galaxy Associated with a z {\tilde}
                                                   2.2
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)
 output.bbl, line 264

Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 
                }
l.264   Damped Ly{$
                   \alpha$} Absorber}.
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.264   Damped Ly{$\alpha
                         $} Absorber}.
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
 output.bbl, line 266

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.266 \newblock \doi
                    {10.3847/2041-8213/aab5b1}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 269

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.269   {Wolfe}}]{2015ApJ...800....7N}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 273

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.273 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1088/0004-637X/800/1/7}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[14]
 output.bbl, line 279

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.279   {York}}]{2012A&A...547L...1N}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 289

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.289 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1051/0004-6361/201220259}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 292

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.292   {Srianand}}]{2009A&A...505.1087N}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 297

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.297 \newblock \doi
                    {10.1051/0004-6361/200912768}.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 300

LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.300   Carvalho}}]{1996ApJ...456L..79P}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
 output.bbl, line 305

.
.
.
.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 \bibcite
             {2016MNRAS.460.1399V}{{55}{2016}{{{Vogelsberger} et~al.}}{{{Vog...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 82

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.82 \bibcite
             {2001ApJ...554...85W}{{56}{2001}{{{Wechsler} et~al.}}{{{Wechsle...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.83 \bibcite
             {2005ARA&A..43..861W}{{57}{2005}{{{Wolfe} et~al.}}{{{Wolfe}, {G...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 83

Misplaced alignment tab character &.

You have placed an alignment tab character '&' in the wrong place. If you want to align something, you must write it inside an align environment such as \begin{align} … \end{align}, \begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}, etc. If you want to write an ampersand '&' in text, you must write \& instead.
 Learn more

l.83 \bibcite{2005ARA&
                      A..43..861W}{{57}{2005}{{{Wolfe} et~al.}}{{{Wolfe}, {G...
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.84 \bibcite
             {1986ApJS...61..249W}{{58}{1986}{{{Wolfe} et~al.}}{{{Wolfe}, {T...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 85

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.85 \bibcite
             {2013yCat..35560141Z}{{59}{2013{}}{{{Zafar} et~al.}}{{{Zafar}, ...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.86 \bibcite
             {2013A&A...556A.140Z}{{60}{2013{}}{{{Zafar} et~al.}}{{{Zafar}, ...
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.aux, line 86

Misplaced alignment tab character &.

You have placed an alignment tab character '&' in the wrong place. If you want to align something, you must write it inside an align environment such as \begin{align} … \end{align}, \begin{tabular} … \end{tabular}, etc. If you want to write an ampersand '&' in text, you must write \& instead.
 Learn more

l.86 \bibcite{2013A&
                    A...556A.140Z}{{60}{2013{}}{{{Zafar} et~al.}}{{{Zafar}, ...
I can't figure out why you would want to use a tab mark
here. If you just want an ampersand, the remedy is
simple: Just type `I\&' now. But if some right brace
up above has ended a previous alignment prematurely,
you're probably due for more error messages, and you
might try typing `S' now just to see what is salvageable.

)
! Undefined control sequence.
\@dofilelist ->\Call@AtVeryEndDocument 
                                       \Call@AtEndAfterFileList 
l.133 \end{document}
 output.aux, line 133

Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

\@dofilelist ...Document \Call@AtEndAfterFileList 

l.133 \end{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
 output.bbl, line 401

Command \~ invalid in math mode on input line 401.
```

I am not sure what is causing the error but it seems that all of them are related to the bibliography file which I don't know if something is wrong with it.

---

**Persistent Error Message:**

```
 Undefined control sequence.

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
 Learn more

l.45 \newblock \jcap
                     {\bf 11}, 059 (2012).
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[83
```

---

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include some file that defines `\mnras`.

Comment: but uabibnat.bst file in the project already should take care of it. Right?

Comment: I have no idea but since you say "Note: I did not include all the necessary files as I merely trying " I was under the impression you did not include the one that defined that macro. At least this is how I read that error message.

Comment: you're right. I cannot see if they are defined. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: I find it. It is defined. I had it commented out. Thanks, but it seems that the nature of the errors changes to something else.

Comment: I tried to do your trick to see if I will get rid of the rest of the errors but it didn't.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Yet you may agree that it is hard to help if one does not have the document and does not know the other error messages you are receiving. The purpose of this site is to solve problems with a code that is shown.

Comment: Always tackle the first error only. Following errors are by *an already confused TeX system*.

Comment: Thanks marmot and Johannes. I added a MWE except that my bibliography file is huge and I don't have it.

Comment: I replaced \usepackage{natbib} with \usepackage[numbers]{natbib} and I resolved my first error.

Comment: except that only the first 43 references are output and all the rest are named number 44 which is weird.

Comment: Related also to the earlier question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472303/35864. Please modify your example to include the suggestions made in the comments here and there so far. Please also try to *minimise* your example in the sense of https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 and show us a few `.bib` example entries.

Comment: Can you please show the bib entry containing `\doi{10.1111/j.1365-2966.2011.19208.x}`?

Comment: The command `\jcap` is undefined. Is it another abbreviation for a journal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bases on your given link in the question and the bib file you gave in your last question I was able to create a MWE for your case here. See the code later.

The error message you got

> ```
> Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
>
> (natbib)                Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.
> ```

Indicates, that you have missed to add options `numbers` to `natbib` to get a **numbered** bibliography (`[1]`) and not a bibliography following author-year citations (`[CMQ2016]`).

To get a simple MWE I just deleted the`\include`d files and simply copied a small code for indroduction (you gave in the last question, it fit's better to your given bib file) into that MWE.  So I got the resulting MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{2016MNRAS.460.1399V,
  author        = {{Vogelsberger}, M. and {Zavala}, J. and {Cyr-Racine}, F.-Y. and {Pfrommer}, C. and {Bringmann}, T. and {Sigurdson}, K.},
  title         = {{ETHOS - an effective theory of structure formation: dark matter physics as a possible explanation of the small-scale CDM problems}},
  journal       = {\mnras},
  year          = {2016},
  volume        = {460},
  pages         = {1399-1416},
  month         = aug,
  adsnote       = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl        = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.460.1399V},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1093/mnras/stw1076},
  eprint        = {1512.05349},
  keywords      = {methods: numerical, galaxies: haloes, dark matter},
}

@Article{2016MNRAS.463.1666C,
  author        = {{Castro}, T. and {Marra}, V. and {Quartin}, M.},
  title         = {{Constraining the halo mass function with observations}},
  journal       = {\mnras},
  year          = {2016},
  volume        = {463},
  pages         = {1666-1677},
  month         = dec,
  adsnote       = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl        = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2016MNRAS.463.1666C},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  doi           = {10.1093/mnras/stw2072},
  eprint        = {1605.07548},
  keywords      = {large-scale structure of Universe, cosmology: observations, cosmological parameters, gravitational lensing: weak, stars: supernovae: general, supernovae: general},
}

@Article{1993MNRAS.264..201K,
  author  = {{Kauffmann}, G. and {White}, S.~D.~M. and {Guiderdoni}, B.},
  title   = {{The Formation and Evolution of Galaxies Within Merging Dark Matter Haloes}},
  journal = {\mnras},
  year    = {1993},
  volume  = {264},
  pages   = {201},
  month   = sep,
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl  = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993MNRAS.264..201K},
  doi     = {10.1093/mnras/264.1.201},
}

@Article{1999ApJ...522...82K,
  author   = {{Klypin}, A. and {Kravtsov}, A.~V. and {Valenzuela}, O. and {Prada}, F.},
  title    = {{Where Are the Missing Galactic Satellites?}},
  journal  = {\apj},
  year     = {1999},
  volume   = {522},
  pages    = {82-92},
  month    = sep,
  adsnote  = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl   = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...522...82K},
  doi      = {10.1086/307643},
  eprint   = {astro-ph/9901240},
  keywords = {COSMOLOGY: THEORY, GALAXIES: CLUSTERS: GENERAL, GALAXIES: INTERACTIONS, GALAXY: FORMATION, GALAXIES: LOCAL GROUP, METHODS: NUMERICAL, Cosmology: Theory, Galaxies: Clusters: General, Galaxies: Interactions, Galaxy: Formation, Galaxies: Local Group, Methods: Numerical},
}

@Article{1999ApJ...524L..19M,
  author   = {{Moore}, B. and {Ghigna}, S. and {Governato}, F. and {Lake}, G. and {Quinn}, T. and {Stadel}, J. and {Tozzi}, P.},
  title    = {{Dark Matter Substructure within Galactic Halos}},
  journal  = {\apjl},
  year     = {1999},
  volume   = {524},
  pages    = {L19-L22},
  month    = oct,
  adsnote  = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl   = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1999ApJ...524L..19M},
  doi      = {10.1086/312287},
  eprint   = {astro-ph/9907411},
  keywords = {COSMOLOGY: OBSERVATIONS, COSMOLOGY: THEORY, COSMOLOGY: DARK MATTER, GALAXIES: CLUSTERS: GENERAL, GALAXIES: FORMATION, Cosmology: Observations, Cosmology: Theory, Cosmology: Dark Matter, Galaxies: Clusters: General, Galaxies: Formation},
}

@Article{2017arXiv171106267K,
  author        = {{Kim}, S.~Y. and {Peter}, A.~H.~G. and {Hargis}, J.~R.},
  title         = {{There is No Missing Satellites Problem}},
  journal       = {ArXiv e-prints},
  year          = {2017},
  month         = nov,
  adsnote       = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System},
  adsurl        = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017arXiv171106267K},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  eprint        = {1711.06267},
  keywords      = {Astrophysics - Cosmology and Nongalactic Astrophysics, Astrophysics - Astrophysics of Galaxies, High Energy Physics - Phenomenology},
}


@Article{Tolman511,
  author    = {Tolman, Richard C.},
  title     = {ON THE ESTIMATION OF DISTANCES IN A CURVED UNIVERSE WITH A NON-STATIC LINE ELEMENT},
  journal   = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  year      = {1930},
  volume    = {16},
  number    = {7},
  pages     = {511--520},
  issn      = {0027-8424},
  doi       = {10.1073/pnas.16.7.511},
  eprint    = {http://www.pnas.org/content/16/7/511.full.pdf},
  publisher = {National Academy of Sciences},
  url       = {http://www.pnas.org/content/16/7/511},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[dissertation,CC-BY-ND]{uathesis}

% Package Usage
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} % <========================================

\usepackage{aastex_hack}% Allows other AASTEX functionality. <==========
\usepackage[%
  bookmarks,
  colorlinks=true,urlcolor=black,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black
]{hyperref}


% Set up some values.
\completetitle{My Lovely Dissertation}
\fullname{Bob Bob Loblaw} % Grad college wants your full name here.
\degreename{Doctor of Philosophy}   % Title of your degree.


\begin{document}

% Set up the title page
\maketitlepage
{DEPARTMENT OF COMPUTER SCIENCE}    % Title of your department.
{2013}                          

\approval
{1 January 1922}        % Defense Date  
{Arnold Abrams}     % Dissertation Director
{Billy Boy}     % 1st committee member
{Carl Crow}     % 2nd committee member
{Donna Dood}            % 3rd committee member
{Edgar Elm} % 4th committee member (leave empty if None)
{} % 5th committee member (leave empty if None)

% Include the ``Statement by Author'' for Dissertations
\statementbyauthor

% Include the ``Acknowledgements''
\incacknowledgements{acknowledgements}

\incdedication{dedication}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{INTRODUCTION\label{chapter:introduction}} % <==================

Some statement \citep{2016MNRAS.460.1399V}. 
Another statement \citep{2016MNRAS.463.1666C}. 
This is known as something. \citep{1993MNRAS.264..201K,1999ApJ...522...82K,1999ApJ...524L..19M}. 
Still another statement \citep{2017arXiv171106267K}. 
Final statement \citep{Tolman511,1934rtc..book.....T,1935ApJ....82..302H,1996ApJ...456L..79P}.

\bibliographystyle{uabibnat}
\bibliography{\jobname} % <=============================================

\end{document}
```

which results in the following bibliography without errors:

[image]

Comment: I just realized this. I guess you also tried to answer the other question posted here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472303/required-files-for-writing-physics-related-thesis/472726#472726

Comment: So this is not a solution just a MWE. Sorry! I was confused.

Comment: all errors are gone except one that is very annoying. I decided to not post another questions with the same title as I didn't find a new one. I am adding the new persistent error message at the very end of this post named, "persistent error message"

Comment: @Allan that error simply means that command `\jcap` is not defined. Define it like the other in `aastex_hack.sty`: copy for example `\newcommand\jrasc{\ref@jnl{JRASC}}% Journal of the RAS of Canada ` and add to your preamble `\newcommand\jcap{\ref@jnl{JCAP}}% Journal of --whatever JCAP means-- `.